# Is it possible to duck under melee attacks by crouching?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm wondering whether its possible to dodge melee attacks by crouching in Fallout 4? I know it works in other games like Dishonored and Resident Evil 7 so I'm curious.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't. The attack will still hit your hitbox.

Comment: Can you provide additional sources for that?

Comment: Experience? @plocks

Comment: There is no physical parry/dodge system in any Fallout game. There is no need for source. It's a well-known design decision.

Comment: It's quite simple to prove this point. In the end it's a BGS game and we do have access to the CK as well as to tools like nifscope. While shooting mechanics got improved quite a bit in this iteration of the engine, melee is pretty much still the same old inaccurate hack-hack-slash-slash we all know and "love" from previous Fallout and TES games.